# How to enable Route::controller in laravel 5.5, is there are any packages to use it?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

As Laravel has deprecated Route Controller and we should explicitly write get/post/put/patch/delete methods.

Also as LaravelCollective return some removed packages as HTML, FORM Helper Classes, is there are any packages return this feature to Laravel 5.3 and above ?

Because many of us use ready made scripts in new projects, to increase our productivity, so we don't re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added to Router.php class, the removed script that was using to handle Route::controller.

I have created a repo on Github for those who like to use Route::controller in Laravel 5.5 and above.

The repo URL is:
https://github.com/marwan2/LaravelRouteControllerBackToLife

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `Route::controller` you could use `Route::resource` which defaults to certain methods. You can change that, customise that as shown [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers).

Here's an example:

**web.php/api.php (Your routes file)**

```
Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController');
```

This will create the following routes:

[image: Laravel Docs]

LaravelCollective/Html is still being supported, so I would take a look at their [GitHub](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html) have a read through their issues page to see if others are running in to similar issues. I don't think their docs are up to date so the best place to check is definitely their GitHub.

Comment: If this worked for you, could you tick it then please?